# sequence number not allowed here in same session

Tags: oracle, database-sequence

How can i get current rule id in a same session because

```
select ID from rules where ID=rules_seq.currval
```

is throwing error :

> ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

Answer (score 3):

You should **save** the sequence value when it is created using `NEXTVAL`.

For example if the `NEXTVAL` is  used in `INSERT` there is a `RETURNING INTO` [clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause) for this purpose.

```
 INSERT INTO my_tab VALUES (seq.nextval, ...)
 RETURNING id INTO v_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a documented limitation of sequences that we cannot use them in a WHERE clause. [Check it here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF00253).

What some may find surprising is that this extends to sub-queries (also documented, as @MarmiteBomber points out):

```
SQL> select * from t23
  2  where t23.id = (select s23.currval from dual)
  3  /
where t23.id = (select s23.currval from dual)
                           *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here


SQL>
```

Of course there is always PL/SQL but it's not very convenient.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2      n pls_integer;
  3      x pls_integer;
  4  begin
  5       n := s23.currval;
  6      select id into x
  7      from t23
  8      where id = n;
  9      dbms_output.put_line('x='||x);
 10  end;
 11  /
x=5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Well, the exclusion in subqueies is documented as well, so I'd say it's   awkward, but not surprising. The reason IMO is that the whole query must guarantie to deliver identical `NEXTVAL` in all calls; which is trivial in `select seq.nextval a, seq.nextval b from dual` , but less trivial in   `select * from (select seq.nextval a from dual),(select seq.nextval b from dual)`

Answer (score 0):

if **ID** is **primary key** or other **index** you can use **index descending** to get maximum id

```
select --+ index_desc (r)
ID 
from rules r 
where rownum=1
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can select the highest ID.

```
select max(ID) from rules
```

This will also get you around the problem that not all numbers generated by the sequence are actually used in a record.

On the other hand, if, in your session, the sequence was used. Why not

```
select rules_seq.currval from dual
```

And finally, if this all takes place in PLSQL you can either return the generated the ID into a variable:

```
declare
   l_id rules.id%type;
begin
  insert into rules (id) 
   values (rules_seq.nextval) 
  returning id into l_id;
end;
```

or assign the sequence value to the variable before the insert.

```
declare
       l_id rules.id%type;
    begin
      l_id := rules_seq.nextval;
      insert into rules (id) 
       values (l_id);
    end;
```

Comment: You're assuming that sequence values are always returned in sequential order. They're not.